# Get all variables in Lua for debug purpose with getinfo / getlocal / getupvalue

Tags: debugging, lua, introspection, love2d

I managed to get almost all variables from my Lua application with this function, but not the ones that are local to a .lua files...

Example at the root of the main.lua :
local test = 10

This cannot be found.

Any idea?

Note: I'm running this in a Love2D app, and this function is called from a Love callback (love.draw).

```
function getvarvalue (name)
    local value, found

    -- try local variables
    local exit = false
    local level = 0
    while debug.getinfo(level) ~= nil do
        local i = 1
        while true do
            local n, v = debug.getlocal(level, i)
            if n then
                print("local "..i.." "..level.." name:"..n)
            end
            if not n then break end
            print(n)
            if n == name then
                value = v
                found = true
            end
            i = i + 1
        end
        if found then return value end
        level = level + 1
    end

    -- try upvalues
    level = 0
    while debug.getinfo(level) ~= nil do
        local func = debug.getinfo(level).func
        i = 1
        while true do
            local n, v = debug.getupvalue(func, i)
            if n~= nil then print("up "..i.." "..level.." "..n) end
            if not n then break end
            if n == name then return v end
            i = i + 1
        end
        if getfenv(func)[name] ~= nil then
            return getfenv(func)[name]
        end
        level = level + 1
    end

    -- not found
    return "?"
end
```

Comment: At the time the callback `love.draw` is invoked the main chunk (where `test` is defined) is already executed and all its local variables (including `local test`) are killed (and only upvalues could survive).

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Yet, I can access this variables from love.draw, so it means they are in the stack somewhere right? So why getvarvalues cannot access them?

Comment: `Yet, I can access this variables` If you can access, but have not accessed it, variable is killed.  Otherwise, it will be found as upvalue.

Comment: You're so right! If I access it from love.draw before calling getvarvalue, it's accessible, otherwise it cannot be found in local or up values. I still cannot understand as the value is here somewere, keeping it's value updated, and I cannot reach it if I do not access it from the function calling getvarvalue.

Answer (score 1):

As @egor-skriptunoff pointed out, local variables, that are unused in a function "get killed". What does it actually mean?
First, Lua treats functions as values, meaning `love.draw` is actually a field, where the assigned value is a function. So the function itself is created at runtime.
Consider this example:

```lua
local myVar = 1

function love.draw()
    print(getvar("myVar"))
end
```

When Lua constructs the function, it checks which upvalues are used. And here the "kill of" happens, it doesn't detect the usage of myVar and then it doesn't create a reference to myVar. Even if it is updated in `love.update`. The debug API then won't show myVar, since it will only show referenced values.
To force Lua to keep a reference, a simple:
`myVar = myVar` in `love.draw` should do the trick.